# Filtering one Table with information in another two different tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

In one table I have the open and close times of different groups of stores on each day. In another table I have different products names and in which stores they are sold. In a third table I have the prices of all products during the whole day (including periods in which the store is closed) for many days.

I need a table with the prices and names of the product only when the respective store is open for each day.

In more details I have the following three tables:

Master, with the columns: name, code, group_name.

StatusChange, with the columns: date, time, group_name, status.

Price, with the columns: date, time, code, price.

The column StatusChange.status has the status of open or close for each group and for each day (A store of a group opens and closes at different times at different days and stores at different groups open and close at different times in a day).

I know I have to use some INNER JOIN at some point, but I am not sure how to write it down with three tables.

I first started with the following join:

```
(SELECT m.*,s.time, s.date FROM Master AS m
INNER JOIN StatusChange AS s ON m.group_name = s.group_name 
WHERE s.status = 'Open' OR s.status = 'close') AS X
```

Which gives me a table with group_name, code, dates and times. From here I should be able to simply INNER JOIN once more and be done. But how does the syntax work exactly?

I tried the following but got an empty result:

```
SELECT p.* FROM Price AS p
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT m.*,s.time, s.date, s.status FROM Master AS m
INNER JOIN StatusChange AS s ON m.group_name = s.group_name 
WHERE s.status = 'Open' OR s.status = 'close') AS X
ON X.date = p.date AND X.code = p.code
WHERE (X.time < p.time AND X.statis = 'Open')
OR  (X.time > p.time AND X.statis = 'Close')
```

Any advice in which part am I making a mistake?

Comment: The meaning of many terms is pretty unclear: What is the meaning of `statuschange`? What is the meaning of `price`? What means *open for each day? Maybe an example would shed light on that.

Comment: You need to write a subquery that gives you group_name, open_time, and close_time.

Comment: Something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15161262/merge-adjacent-rows-in-sql
One you have that, suppose it is name "t", you can INNER JOIN t ON group_name.  Then you can say WHERE (p.time >= t.open AND p.time < t.close) for each part of open/close times.

Comment: Since it is hard for people to work on a query without examples, you might get more responses if you posted some CREATE TABLE statements and INSERT statements that allowed someone else to create your scenario.  It's like creating an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for SQL questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH sub as (
  SELECT 
    m.name, m.code, m.group_name, s.time, s.date, s.status 
  FROM 
    Master m, StatusChange s
  WHERE
    m.group_name = s.group_name 
    AND (s.status = 'Open' OR s.status = 'close'))

SELECT 
  p.date, p.time, p.code, p.price, x.name, x.group_name, x.status 
FROM 
  Price p, sub x
WHERE
  sub.date = p.date 
  AND sub.code = p.code
  AND ((x.time < p.time AND x.status = 'Open') OR (x.time > p.time AND x.status = 'Close'))
```

Comment: I think this only works if there is only a single Open time and a single Close time.  If the store closes at 20:00 today, and opens at 9:00 tomorrow, then a price at a time of 21:00 today will still match your query since it is less than 9:00 tomorrow.  But it should not.